# Taskbar disappears sometimes when using a second monitor

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, multiple-monitors

Windows 7 laptop, docked with a second monitor.  This problem started happening when I started using the second monitor.

The taskbar will often stop displaying.  The Windows logo remains, but the bar, system tray, clock, and any icons for minimized programs disappear.  I can see part of my desktop wallpaper where the taskbar should be.  The taskbar is not set to auto-hide. Killing the explorer.exe process and starting it again temporarily fixes this.  Is there a permanent solution?